# flutter GestureDetector with the flutter map or mapbox

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fluttermap

I am new in the flutter and my problem is when the GestureDetector child is a flutter map a OnTapUp method not response
but when the child is a container every things work fine.
How to get response from OnTapUp when GestureDetector  child is a flutter map?

Comment: have you find any solution for this problem..??

Answer (score 1):

For FlutterMap options you can find for example onTap method.

FlutterMap(
mapController: _mapController,
options: MapOptions(
onTap: (tapPosition, point) {}),)

You don't need to use GestureDetector.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add one event listener to a single event.

The mapbox widget (and any other map widget) will take the OnTapUp event, so you cannot listen to it a second time.

Comment: but do you know how i can detect the onTapUp event or somethings like that that help me to catch this event?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a stack and create button over it with transparent background.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).